# Port forward on a new Huawei - HG8247W5 router

Tags: router, wireless-router, port-forwarding, ipv4

I searched the internet for a solution, however no-one seem to have this particular problem trying to port forward on a HG8247W5 Huawei router.
This is how I tried to setup the port mapping:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIeyK.png)

As you can see at "Internal Host" I set the local iPv4 that is returned in cmd from ipconfig
I added, 2 ports, oe UDP, orne TCP set with 80(I left blank the "External source port number")

At "External Source IP Address" I put the public iPv4 of the router that google told me when I searched "what is my ip".

The problem is that "WAN name" is a HTML `<select>` drop-down without any `<option>`, the list of options is blank. If I try to click Apply, it says "Create a WAN Port first".

Now if I switch to the WAN tab on the top menu, an empty table with these headers appear:
`Connection Name      VLAN/Priority      Protocol Type`
       `-                   -                  -`

Even if the table is empty I don't have any "`+`" button like on the port mapping configuration menu. It doesn't give me the option to add an entry to this table.

On the "Status" tab on the menu, at the "WAN Info" option, I have these 2 entries:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9xVQ.png)

From the tutorials I've seen, I think the "VoIP" entry is the one that needs to be referenced in the port mapping menu. However, as you can see, in the image above, it says "Connecting", **not** "Connected". I tried to reset the router, I tried to restart it, it says "Connecting".

I noticed that the status tab has a "VoIP Info" option. You can take a look at it here(I guess it is important) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqHHW.png)

Now, as far as I understand, this happens because my internet provider(Orange - European Company, Americans probable don't know about it) decided not to allow users to create a WAN Port without a static global IP, which is a paid service. I don't know if this is true, however if it is true seems unfair.

Comment: Do you have VOIP service through your ISP? If you don’t then I would not expect VOIP to be relevant to your problem. On first screenshot have you tried hitting Add? Are you behind a CGNAT?

Comment: I don't know what is VOPI or ISP. On the first screenshot, the add button adds an port entry, I already added 2 ports 80: TCP and 80:UDP. Yes I think I am behind a CGNAT. When I search what is my ip address on google, I receive a iPv6(2a02:a58:8242:bc00:5ca1:a59f:1b88:6a36). When I access this website: https://whatismyipaddress.com/ I see my iPv4. As far as I understand, when iPv6 is the default IP address, the iPv4 is somehow generated as a requested thing.

Comment: You don’t know what VOIP is? Voice over IP, I.e phone over internet, sounds like you don’t have a land line with your ISP in that case. You can’t typically port forward if your behind a CGNAT.

Comment: Can I speak with the provider to set up a fixed iPv4